# Filing Sent messages in a folder other than sent messages folder

Tags: mail.app, email, gmail, imap

Is there a way to create a rule in Apple Mail that will copy every sent message to another folder? I want to have every sent message to be copied to the G-Mail IMAP folder so that all my sent mail is on the server. It won't do it automatically because of the way I have my return address set up in the G-Mail Account
. 
I can copy them individually, but I'd like it to happen automatically.

I understand that El Capitan has fixed IMAP in Apple Mail and handles it properly, but I can't upgrade to El Capitan until all my professional applications are solid. And they are not.

MacPro 3,1

OSX 10.10.5

Thanx in advance for any help you might have!

best,

Fred

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing this for quite a while. Mac mail does not do it for you. However is works in this way: every sent message has an automatic copy to myself. In a rule I copy the received message with myself as the sender to a mailbox xxx.
1.Mail / Preferences / check Automatically Bcc: myself
2. Mail / Preferences / Rules / Add rule / "if any of the following conditions are met": from - contains -  Move message to Mailbox 
good luck!

Comment: Thanks so much Jan. I really appreciate it. I never thought of attacking it in that way. Very clever. Although - and this is the OS's fault - it doesn't allow us to do it very elegantly! I understand that El Capitan fixes this.....But I can't upgrade...